# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent Query Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, eloquera

I want to optimize Laravel query for product listing. I need to display product listing as well as brands. Following is the code:

```
$searchTerm = 'Coffee';
$productListing = Product::where('title', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->paginate(10);
```

I also need separate list for all brands for products returned by search.

Method 1:

Get all brand ids in array

```
$productBrandsArray = $productListing->pluck('brand_id')->toArray();
```

Problem is this will only get brands for 10 records because of products pagination

```
$productBrands = Brand::whereIn('brand_id', $productBrandsArray);
```

Method 2 (Sub-Query):

```
$productBrands = Brand::whereIn('brand_id', function ($query) use($searchTerm) {
$query->select('brand_id')
->from(with(new Product())->getTable())
->where(Product::getTableName().'.title', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');});
```

Currently I am using sub-query method to get results but I think its not optimized because same search query is executed multiple times.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem lies with the wildcards, you can't optimize a query that uses `LIKE '%text%'` because it won't be able to use an index, so you need to remove the first wildcard in order to speed this query up.

Comment: Consider using a `FULLTEXT` index.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is working in the bases of limit and offset, so you have to make a second query in order to get the whole brands. In the Method 1 to get product brands you can change the query as given below so you don't need get the brands id separately.

```
$productBrands = Brand::where('products.title', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
                ->join("products", "brands.brand_id", "=", "products.brand_id")
                ->get();
```